# Javascript Map (Object) doesn't format correctly

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, javascript-objects

I have an array of Maps, each looks like this in the console:
[image]

```
Map[10]
{"chartType" => "horizontalBar"}
{"data" => 
List[4]
}
{"description" => "Everything black"}
{"detailUrl" => ""}
{"featuredStepIndex" => 1}
{"id" => 542}
{"isValid" => false}
{"stepIndex" => 1}
{"type" => "results"}
```

I have a React component that takes this array of Maps and renders the output. I am trying to take another data source and format it like above to pass to the React component.

When I create the array of new Maps using the code below:

﻿﻿

```
resultsSteps.forEach((item) => {
    const newMapStep = new Map();    
    newMapStep.chartType = 'horizontalBar';
    const itemDescription = item.get('description');
    newMapStep.description = itemDescription;
    newMapStep.featured = 'false';
    newMapStep.detailUrl = '';
    newMapStep.featuredStepIndex = 1;
    const itemId = item.get('id');
    newMapStep.id = itemId;
    newMapStep.isValid = 'false';
    newMapStep.type = 'results';
    const itemOptions = item.get('options');
    newMapStep.data = itemOptions;
    const itemAnswers = item.get('userAnswers');
    newMapStep.userAnswers = itemAnswers;

    newResultsSteps.push(newMapStep);
  });
```

I get a Map object that looks different in the console:

[image]

```
Map
chartType
:
"horizontalBar"
data
:
List[4]
description
:
"Everything black"
detailUrl
:
""
featured
:
"false"
featuredStepIndex
:
1
id
:
542
isValid
:
"false"
type
:
"results"
userAnswers
:
List[2]
_c
:
Map(0) {}
size
:
(...)
__proto__
:
Map
```

...which doesn't look like the one it's replacing, which has {'' => '' } for each entry. How can I create a new Map that matches that syntax?

Comment: 1) Why do you care what it looks like in the *console*? and 2) that's not how you add Map entries, use `set`.

Comment: Because the React component expects the data in a particular format, and the format for the newly created Map doesn't match the prior format, and as such it's not rendering properly in the component.

Comment: You're just attaching object properties to the `Map` object. Use the `.set` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set).

Comment: Using the .set method instead of dot annotation for each set yields the same result. The linter prefers dot annotation so that's what I used.

Comment: The console can display whatever it wants to, there is nothing in the ECMAScript spec that says a Map has to display `({key => value})`. You'll have to look at the documentation of that particular React component.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Chrome 64 doesn't care whether I do `new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])` or `foo = new Map();foo.set('a', 1);foo.set('b', 2);` I get `Map(2) {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}` either way. Adding the values as object properties gives me what you posted. And if your linter says that, your linter is **wrong**. Adding an object property to a map and adding a value via `.set` are completely different operations.

Comment: To wit: `Object.keys(new Map([['a', 1]]))` yields an empty array, `Object.keys((foo=new Map(), foo.a = 1, foo))` yields `['a']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .set method

```
resultsSteps.forEach((item) => {
    const newMapStep = new Map();    
    newMapStep.set('chartType', 'horizontalBar');    
});
```